# Measure on intersections of unions

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},μ)$ a measurable space and let $A_1,A_2,...∈\mathcal{A}$, assume that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}=\mu (A_j)<\infty$

We have $E=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}(A_k)$

I want to show that $\mu(E)=0$

what I've done so far is that for an element x in E, we have

$x\in A_k$ for atleast one $k\ge n$ but for all $n$, so x must be in $A_k$ for infinite k's.

I'm not sure if that's right, or where I can go from here.

Comment: $E = \limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n$, so $\mu(E) = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)$ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use monotonicity: $\mu(E) \le \displaystyle \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\right)$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Use subadditivity: $\displaystyle \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\right) \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu(A_k)$.

Conclude: $\displaystyle \mu(E) \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu(A_k)$ for all $n \ge 1$.

What happens as $n \to \infty$?